# How should I get CMake to also create PTX files for my kernels

Tags: build, cmake, cuda, ptx

I'm building a project with CUDA code, using a recent CMake which has intrinsic CUDA support (version >= 3.8 or later if necessary).

How do I tell CMake to (also) generate PTX files for my various kernels?

#### Something I've tried which doesn't (?) work:

Beginning with CMake 3.9, we can define an object library to have PTXes rather than kinds of objects, using the [`CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION.html):

```
add_library(myptx OBJECT a.cu b.cu)
set_property(TARGET myptx PROPERTY CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION ON)
```

However, this isn't a proper solution to the problem - something is missing. Suppose we have in `a.cu`:

```
__global__ void foo() { return; }
```

and in `b.cu`:

```
__global__ void bar(int* a) { *a = 5; }
```

and we run `cmake` and `make` with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
add_library(myptx OBJECT a.cu b.cu)
set_property(TARGET myptx PROPERTY CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION ON)
```

no PTX files get generated and nvcc isn't run. Not sure why.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Moved the half-answer into the question.

Comment: What do you want the PTX for?  Appropriately compiled binary payloads contain both PTX and SASS. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @talonmies: I don't mind whether the PTX is extracted from the binary, aposteriori. I just want to inspect the PTX code as well as build the binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning on CUDA language.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
enable_language(CUDA)
add_library(myptx OBJECT a.cu b.cu)
set_property(TARGET myptx PROPERTY CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION ON)
```

PTXs are located in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/myptx.dir`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `--keep` command-line option to nvcc, which will make it keep all intermediate files in the same directory it's using for other outputs. With newer CMake versions, you would write:

```
target_compile_options(
    some_target
    another_target
    yet_another_target_etc
    PRIVATE 
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:--keep
)
```

(The reason for using the generator expression rather than just saying `--keep` is the case of targets with some sources in CUDA and other sources in other languages.)

This will work, and it seems the `.ptx` ends up where the binary is. But - note you'll also get a gazillion other files: `.cpp4.ii`, `.cudafe1.c`, `.cudafe1.cpp`, `.fatbin` and so on. So, this is still a kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mentioned, you can pass the `--keep` command-line option to nvcc. But cmake file should be written like this:

```
target_compile_options(youtarget PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:--keep>)
```

means the `--keep` option will not be passed to host compilers like gcc, which will cause `error: unrecognized command line option ‘--keep’`

Comment: You mean, for the case of a target having both CUDA and non-CUDA sources? Hmm, good point, +1 on that. But it's still not the "right" solution, just a sort of a hack...